# Plupload callback get file md5

Tags: callback, plupload, md5-file

Plupload plugin callback get uploaded file md5.

Plupload has the same question, but others can't get the right answer.

Below code is my test. please confirm.

- import spark-md5

```html
<!-- spark-md5 -->
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/spark-md5/3.0.0/spark-md5.js"></script>
```

- calc md5 method

```js
// file md5 method
function calculate(file, callBack) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader(),
        blobSlice = File.prototype.mozSlice || File.prototype.webkitSlice || File.prototype.slice,
        chunkSize = 2097152,
        // read in chunks of 2MB
        chunks = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize),
        currentChunk = 0,
        spark = new SparkMD5();
    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
        spark.appendBinary(e.target.result); // append binary string
        currentChunk++;
        if (currentChunk < chunks) {
            loadNext();
        } else {
            callBack(spark.end());
        }
    };

    function loadNext() {
        let start = currentChunk * chunkSize,
            end = start + chunkSize >= file.size ? file.size : start + chunkSize;
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(blobSlice.call(file, start, end));
    };
    loadNext();
}
```

- file upload callback get file md5

```js
// 文件上传回调
function uploadCallback(status, remote_path, filename, callback_params, file) {
    // 调用计算md5的方法
    calculate(file.getNative(), function(md5) {
        console.log(md5); //hash值
    });
    // other code ....
    // ....
});
```

Plupload
https://www.phpin.net/tools/plupload/

Comment: What is the question? Please be explicit.

Comment: I've solved the question.

Answer (score 0):

I used this web site calc file md5 compare with up code.
It's right.

[HTML5 File Hash Online Calculator](https://md5file.com/calculator)